# Rails no action "edit" in forum_posts_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The forum_posts controller is located in app/controllers/forum_threads/forum_posts_controller.rb

I don't know if I have to call forum_threads:forum_posts in the link_to.

Controller:

http://pastebin.com/t9vuyxdP

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/LextuZ74

On a side note, how do you add a button to the link_to? I've tried adding :class => "button" at the end, doesn't cause an error but still just shows a link not a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `link_to` with older-style controller/action/id arguments:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", :controller => "forum_threads/forum_posts", :action => "edit", :id => forum_post.id, :forum_thread_id => @forum_thread.id %>
```

But Rails prefer newer RESTful routes whenever possible. If you define your controller correctly in `routes.rb`, you can write `link_to` like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_forum_thread_forum_post_path(@forum_thread, forum_post) %>
```

**UPDATE 18/11/2015: You forgot to include `forum_thread_id` in `link_to` as I saw your route require `forum_thread_id` and `id` param to make it work.**

> For more information on `link_to`, refer to: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: @user3468440 the reason for `RAILS_ENV=production rake routes` is that you've not made routes for all your controller action . you should run `bundle exec rake routes` before proceeding

Comment: @user3468440 I updated my answer according to your `routes`. In both way, you have to provide both `forum_thread_id` and `id` (the id of forum post you want to edit) to `link_to` function to make it works as your your require both id.